# How to retrieve R function script from a specific package?

Tags: r

I realize there are generic functions like `plot`, `predict` for a list of packages. I am wondering how could I get the R script of these generic functions for a specific package, like the lme4::predict. I tried lme4::predict, but it comes with error:

```
> lme4::predict
Error: 'predict' is not an exported object from 'namespace:lme4'
```

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think yo want `lme4:::predict.merMod`

Comment: Usually if `package::function` doesnt work, try `getAnywhere(function)`. Tough you will have to specify it exactly, i.e, the S3 method rather than the generic function

Comment: lme4:::predict.merMod is what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you state that my suggestion above was helpful I will tell you my process.  I used my own co-authored package called [pacman](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pacman/index.html).  This package was developed because we had a hard time remembering all the obscurely named functions to get information on and work with add on packages.

I used this to figure out what you wanted:

```
library(pacman)
p_funs(lme4, all=TRUE)
```

I set `all = TRUE` as `predict` is a method for a specific class (like `print`, `summary` and `plot`).  Generally, these methods are not exported so `p_funs` won't return them unless you set `all = TRUE`.  Then I scrolled down to the `p` section and found only a single `predict` method: `predict.merMod`

Next I realized it wasn't exported so `::` won't show me the stuff and extra colon power is needed, hence: `lme4:::predict.merMod`

As pointed out by David and rawr above, some functions can be suborn little snippets (methods etc.), thus `methods` and `getAnywhere` are helpful.

Here is an example of that:

```
library(tm)
dissimilarity  #The good stuff is hid

methods(dissimilarity)  #I want the good stuff
getAnywhere("dissimilarity.DocumentTermMatrix")
```

***Small end note***

And of course you don't need `pacman` to look at functions for packages, it's what I use and helpful but it just wraps base R things.  Use [THE SOURCE](https://github.com/trinker/pacman/blob/master/R/p_functions.R) to figure out exactly what.